# Why does golang prohibit assignment to same underlying type when one is a native type?

Tags: go

Consider this code:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type specialString string

func printString(s string) {
    fmt.Println(s)
}

// unlike, say, C++, this is not legal GO, because it redeclares printString
//func printString(s specialString) {    
//  fmt.Println("Special: " + s)
//}

func main() {
    ss := specialString("cheese")
    // ... so then why shouldn't this be allowed?
    printString(ss)
}
```

My question is: *why* is the language defined so that the call to `printString(ss)` in `main()` is not allowed? (I'm not looking for answers that point to the Golang rules on assignment; I have already read them, and I see that both specialString and string have the same 'underlying type' and both types are 'named' -- if you consider the generic type 'string' to be named, which Golang apparently does -- and so they are not assignable under the rules.)

But *why* are the rules like that? What problem is solved by treating the built-in types as 'named' types, and preventing you from passing named types to all the standard library functions that accepting the same underlying built-in type? Does anybody know what the language designers had in mind here?

From my point of view, it seems to create a lot of pointless type conversion in the code, and *discourages* the use of strong typing where it actually would make sense..

Comment: Safety reasons only. Strong strict typing makes errors less likely. Your example where you use a "specialstring" implies that it is a string and one might get the impression of subtyping which Go does not have. You introduce a `type foobar string` to have a foobar (which actually is a string), but why should it make sense to print a foobar with your printstring function? A foobar is not `string`, it is foobar. If a plain string is all you need, then there is no need to introduce a "specialstring", just use plain string.

Comment: Also here is some more reasoning in the official FAQ: [Why does Go not provide implicit numeric conversions?](http://golang.org/doc/faq#conversions)

Comment: Also consider the design of parts of the library like `time.Duration`.  The language prevents plain `int64`s from being treated as `time.Duration` without the expliclt units consideration.  The feature that you're critiquing can (and is!) used to encode the "same units" rule we know from middle school.  When used well, it should make it more difficult to make the same kinds of mistakes that sends satellites crashing out of the sky due to a metric conversion error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the initial authors' logic here is that named type is named for a reason - it represents something different, not just underlying type.

I guess I've read it somewhere in golang-nuts, but can't remember exact discussion.

Consider the following example:

```
type Email string
```

You named it Email, because you need to represent e-mail entity, and 'string' is just simplified representation of it, sufficient for the very start. But later, you may want to change Email to something more complex, like:

```
type Email struct {
    Address string
    Name    string
    Surname string
}
```

And that will break all your code that work with Email implicitly assuming it's a string.

Comment: **I am totally not agree**. Go allow to do indexing for `type Email string`. `Email[:]` is valid in first case but definitely will cause a compilation error at the second one. Turn out that it will not save developers from _shooting yourself in the foot_.  I also questioned this question and decided for myself that it's an opinionated decision among early golang developers. And I need to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

This is because Go does not have class inheritance. It uses struct composition instead. Named types do not inherit properties from their underlying type (that's why it's not called "base type").

So when you declare a named type `specialString` with an underlying type of a predefined type `string`, your new type is a completely different type from the underlying one. This is because Go assumes you will want to assign different behaviors to your new type, and will not check its underlying type until run-time. This is why Go is both a static and dynamic language.

When you print

```
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(ss))        // specialString
```

You get `specialString`, not `string`. If you take a look at `Println()` the definition is as follows:

```
func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error) {
        return Fprintln(os.Stdout, a...)
}
```

This means you can print any predeclared types (int, float64, string) because all of them implements **at least zero methods**, which makes them already conform to the empty interface and pass as "printable", but not your named type `specialString` which remains unknown to Go during compile time. We can check by printing the type of our `interface{}` against `specialString`.

```
type specialString string 
type anything interface{}

s := string("cheese")
ss := specialString("special cheese")
at := anything("any cheese")

fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(ss))     // specialString
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(s))      // string
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(at))     // Wow, this is also string!
```

You can see that `specialString` keeps being naughty to its identity. Now, see how it does when passed into a function at run-time

```
func printAnything(i interface{}) {
        fmt.Println(i)
}

fmt.Println(ss.(interface{}))       // Compile error! ss isn't interface{} but
printAnything(ss)                   // prints "special cheese" alright
```

`ss` has become passable as `interface{}` to the function. By that time Go has already made `ss` an `interface{}`.

If you really want to understand deep down the hood this [article on interfaces](http://research.swtch.com/interfaces) is really priceless.

Comment: I found this answer informative, and so I up-voted it, but ultimately I  selected divan's answer, because his answer was more directly aimed at the crux of my question: "what problem does this solve?" -- I was really looking for "why did the language designers think this behavior was a good idea" rather than "what aspects of the language's implementation cause it to work this way?" -- nevertheless I thank you for taking the time to explain in such excellent detail.

Answer (score 0):

It's called nominal typing. It simply means that the type is identified by it's name and it has to be made explicit to be useful.

From a convenience point of view it is easy to critique but it super useful.

For example, let's say you have a parameter to a function that is a string but it cannot be just any string, there are rules you need to check. If you change the type from string to something that implies that you checked the string for potential problems you made a good design decision because it's now clear from just looking at the code that the string needs to go via some function to validate the input first (and enrich it's type in the process).

```golang
type Validated string
func Validate(input string): (Validated, err) {
  return Validated(input), nil // assuming you actually did validate the string
}
```

Go makes these tradeoffs because it does improve readability (i.e. the ability of someone unfamiliar with your code to quickly understand how things work) and that's something they (the Go language designers) value above all else.